# Remark 16(i) in Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $I = (a, b)$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval of $\mathbb R$. I would like to verify *Remark 16(i)* at page 218 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> For $u:I \to \mathbb R$, we define $\bar u:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
> $$
> \bar u (x) :=
> \begin{cases}
> u (x) &\text{if} \quad x \in I, \\
> 0 &\text{if} \quad x \in \mathbb R \setminus I.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Let $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $u \in W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ IFF $\bar u \in W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)$.

Above $W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ is the closure of $C^1_c (I)$ in $W^{1, p} (I)$. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

WLOG, we assume $I=(0, \infty)$.

1. $\implies$

Let $u \in W^{1, p}_0 (I)$. Clearly, $\bar u \in L^p (\mathbb R)$. We define $v$ by
$$
v (x) :=
\begin{cases}
u' (x) &\text{if} \quad x \in I, \\
0 &\text{if} \quad x \in \mathbb R \setminus I.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $v \in L^p (\mathbb R)$. It follows from $u(0)=0$ that $\bar u (0) = u(0)$ and thus
$$
\bar u (x) - \bar u (0) = \int_0^x v(t) dt
\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R.
$$

> **Remark 7** The primitive $v$ of a function $g \in L^p (I)$ belongs to $W^{1, p} (I)$ provided we also know that $v \in L^p (I)$, which is always the case when $I$ is bounded.

The claim then follows from *Remark 7* (in the same book).

- $\impliedby$

Let $\bar u \in W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)$. Then $u = \bar u |_I \in W^{1, p} (I)$. Clearly, $u(0) = \bar u (0)=0$.

> **Theorem 8.12** Let $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$. Then $u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)$ if and only if $u=0$ on $\partial I$.

The claim then follows from *Theorem 8.12*.

Comment: Looks fine to me.