# Remark 16(ii) in Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $I = (a, b)$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval of $\mathbb R$. I would like to verify *Remark 16(ii)* at page 218 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $p \in (1, \infty)$. Then $u \in W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ IFF there is a constant $C>0$ such that
> $$
> \left | \int_I u \varphi' \right | \le C \| \varphi\|_{L^{p'} (I)}
> \quad \forall \varphi \in C^1_c (\mathbb R).
> $$

Above,

- $W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ is the closure of $C^1_c (I)$ in $W^{1, p} (I)$.
- $p'$ the Hölder conjugate of $p$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We need two results from the same book

> - **Proposition 8.3** Let $u \in L^p (I)$ with $p \in (1, \infty]$. Then $u \in W^{1, p} (I)$ IFF there is a constant $C>0$ such that
>   $$
>   \left|\int_I u \varphi' \right| \leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^{p'}(I)}
>   \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(I) .
>   $$
> - [Remark 16(i)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765815/remark-16i-in-brezis-functional-analysis) For $u:I \to \mathbb R$, we define $\bar u:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
>   $$
>   \bar u (x) :=
>   \begin{cases}
>   u (x) &\text{if} \quad x \in I, \\
>   0 &\text{if} \quad x \in \mathbb R \setminus I.
>   \end{cases}
>   $$
>   Let $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $u \in W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ IFF $\bar u \in W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)$.

By *Remark 16(i)*, $u \in W^{1, p}_0 (I)$ IFF $\bar u \in W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)$. By *Proposition 8.3*, $\bar u \in W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)$ IFF there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\left| \int_\mathbb R \bar u \varphi' \right| \leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^{p'}(I)}
\quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1( \mathbb R) .
$$

The proof then follows by the fact that
$$
\int_\mathbb R \bar u \varphi' = \int_I u \varphi'.
$$